# Java : Fetch data from arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, linked-list

I have arraylist which has input data like `[1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9]`.

But the output should be `[7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5]`.

The last 3 values should come first. I dont know how do we do it in `ArrayList`. I think it is possible in `linkedlist`.

Below is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class iterate{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (Integer i : Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
            numbers.add(i);
        printList(numbers);         // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

     }

}
```

This is what i know. Now how do i proceed

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about rotating the values of the list?

Comment: yes...i have showed the input as well as the output..i tried a lot..i dont understand what to do

Comment: Show some code with your efforts. You see you might be close, better we fix problems in your code than just do it for you.

Comment: Are you trying to reorder the elements in the list, or just trying to print them in that order?

Comment: i want to reorder them and print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> array = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9);
Collections.rotate(array, 3);
array.forEach(e -> System.out.print(e+" "));
```